# Button color is not changed.Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, colors

Every time when I want to change color of button through xml, color is not changed and stays in default color. When I change color through java code, color changes but totally to another color which i don't want. Now I am changing colors of buttons by changing default color in themes.xml file.

I tried a lot of ways on Youtube , searched old answers on stackoverflow but could not solve the issue.
How can I fix this problem in my Android Studio?

Comment: We can't tell you what is wrong without any code at all. Take a look at [ask] and how to produce a [mre] so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style to eliminate the Tinte, put the `backgroundTint` on *@null* and everything should work .

here is the style I added

```
 <style name="NotTintedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
 </style>
```

And all you have to do is apply this style on your buttons. for example :

```
 <Button        
        style="@style/NotTintedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```